# Fiddler: Google.com redirecting to local page

Tags: http, header, fiddler

I was given a task to Host: www.google.com behavior with accept-language flag. But no matter what header i compose in composer in fiddler google.com redirects me to my local page.

for example

```
Host: www.google.com
User-Agent: fiddler
Accept-Language: en;q=1
```

is completly ignored by google and redirected to my local page with my local language

I have tried using www.google.com/ncr but it redirects my anyway. Is there any way to prevent that redirection to local?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google typically uses IP-based Geolocation to decide what page to serve you; it will offer an "in-page" switcher UI if your Accept-Language is something unexpected. So you'd want to use a remote proxy (e.g. TOR, GeoEdge) in the target country to accomplish this goal.